# After guard let url the value still needs to be unwrapped

Tags: swift, swift-guard

In [a singleton class](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/blob/master/Tops1/Tops1/Managers/DownloadManager.swift) I am trying the following code with 3 URLs stored in a dictionary:

```
class DownloadManager {
    static let instance = DownloadManager()
    
    let urls = [
        "en" : URL(string: "https://wordsbyfarber.com/ws/top"),
        "de" : URL(string: "https://wortefarbers.de/ws/top"),
        "ru" : URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")
    ]
    
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    private init() {
        getTops()
    }
    
    func getTops() {
        guard let url = urls["en"] else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url) // COMPILE ERROR
            .tryMap(handleOutput)
            .decode(type: TopResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink { completion in
                print(completion)
            } receiveValue: { fetchedTops in
                // ... store entities in Core Data
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

But for some reason the line `guard let url = urls["en"] else { return }` is not sufficient to unwrap the value:

[image: screenshot]

Is this happening because the `URL` constructor might return nil?

Or because of the dictionary might not have a value for a key?

And why is guard statement not enough here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urls` is actually of type `[String: URL?]`. Note that the value type is optional, because `URL.init(string:)` is failable.

When you try to get a value from this dictionary, you get a `URL??`. The `guard` only unwraps one layer of the optional.

One way to unwrap a nested optional (no matter how many layers), is to use `as?`:

```
guard let url = urls["en"] as? URL else { return }
```

Comment: Ah, there are "layers of optionality"? I am still learning Swift

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Yes, you can have `URL?`, `URL??`, `URL???` etc. You can add arbitrarily many question marks at the end. For `URL??`, there are 3 cases, it can be totally nil (`.none`), or the outer optional is not nil but the inner optional is nil (`.some(.none)`), or there can be an actual URL in there (`.some(.some(http://example.com))`).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber These cases correspond to "the dictionary lookup failed", "URL's initialiser failed but the dictionary lookup succeeded" and "both succeeded" respectively.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber There's nothing special about optionals. You can nest them the same way you can nest arrays or dictionaries with other arrys or dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this happening because the URL constructor might return nil?

Yes.

```
let urls = [
    "en" : URL(string: "https://wordsbyfarber.com/ws/top"),
    "de" : URL(string: "https://wortefarbers.de/ws/top"),
    "ru" : URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")
]
```

creates a dictionary with optional URLs (`[String: URL?]`), and your unwrapping only relates to the contents of the dictionary.

Use

```
let urls = [
    "en" : URL(string: "https://wordsbyfarber.com/ws/top")!,
    "de" : URL(string: "https://wortefarbers.de/ws/top")!,
    "ru" : URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")!
]
```

for hardcoded URLs like this, or double-unwrap if it's unclear if the URLs are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Thats as `Url` initializer returns an optional + the optional wrap of the `Dictionary` , If you're sure that all urls are valid then

```
 guard let url = urls["en"] else { return } 
 URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!) // add only !
```

or only

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: urls["en"]!!)   // add !!
```

Comment: @AlexanderFarber probably, but it would get confusing for both you and someone else if they are reading your code later